# Conditional Mean and Variance for $f(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

$f(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y<\infty$

Determine the marginal density of $X$:
$\int_x^\infty 2 \cdot e^{-(x+y)} dy= 2 e^{-2x}$ for $x>0$

Which is an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=2$

Determine the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$:

$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=(2e^{-(x+y)})/(2e^{-2x})=e^{-(y-x)}$ for $0<x<y<\infty$

$P(Y>2|X=1)=1/e=0.36788$

Given the support, we know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Determine the conditional mean of $Y$ given $X=x$:

$E(Y|X)=\int_x^\infty y \cdot e^{-(y-x)}dy=x+1$

Determine the conditional variance of $Y$ given $X=x$.

Is what I have above correct? How do I find the conditional variance of $Y$ given $X=x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the definition of the conditional variance or compute both the conditional expectation $E(Y|x)$ and $E(Y^2|x)$.

We have an analogous identity of
 $$ Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2. $$

Comment: Is $E(Y|X)$ correct?

Comment: Yes. However, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.